# How to redirect only newest line of output to file dynamically?

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following output:

```
artist - song name
artist - song name
artist - song name
```

When one song ends, the program prints next artist and song name in a new line.
I want to pipe the output somehow and save only the latest entry to the file in the way that when there's a new entry, it overwrites the file.

Is it possible with simple piping in bash? Or do I have to write some wrapper script for that?

Comment: `yourprogram | tail -1 > outputfile` should do the job, where `yourprogram` is whatever you use to generate that output you mention. However I have downvoted your question as the desired workflow is totally unclear.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis, isn't `tail` waiting for the program to end and then fetches the last line?

Comment: Have you checked for `tail`'s `-f` option? I'm referring to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45626/output-file-contents-while-they-change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's mock a program that prints a new artist / song title every few seconds with a shell function:

```sh
printsong() {
    local i=0
    while :; do
        echo "artist - song $((++i))"
        sleep 3
    done
}
```

Now, we read from this function, and overwrite a file every time we get a new line:

```
printsong | while IFS= read -r song; do echo "$song" > output; done
```

`output` will now always contain the most recent line of output from `printsong`.